# Looking for a window (32 bit) software that will host a VST plugin.

Tags: plugin, vst

Hello everybody,

I will be thankful for your advice-

I purchased an instrument vst plugin.

I am looking for a window (32 bit) software that will host the plugin, and-

1. Will be able to record the sounds, created with the hosted instrument plugin.
2. will be able to export the files to *FLAC or/and OGG* format and in HD( like 96.000 Hz , 32-bit) directly from the software (without any converting)
3. That the price of the software will be up to 100$ if possible(I am willing to buy the software and not looking for free ones)
4. Easy to use software.

Any suggestions will be thankfully welcome.

*Thank you* :-)

Answer (score 2):

REAPER - http://www.reaper.fm/

Answer (score 0):

2nd Reaper for that price range. I use reaper alongside my Cubase7 DAW and find it's features very useful for recording the loop back on my sound card. I can also use it in rewire mode within Cubase should I need to. For the money it's a really great program.

Answer (score 0):

Hello again and *many thanks* for the info.

If any other software (under 100$) comes to mind, I will
be thankful to also know about it.

Thank you! :-)